# How can I make a C++ program hide the source file path from the "strings" command?

Tags: c++, c, string, cmake, strip

The `strings` command allows you to search for strings in binary files.

So if I use the `strings` command and search for .cc with grep, I get the following results.

```bash
strings myProgram | grep '.cc'

> 
...
{hidden}/vcpkg/buildtrees/gflags/src/v2.2.2-d51934acae.clean/src/gflags.cc
{hidden}/vcpkg/buildtrees/gflags/src/v2.2.2-d51934acae.clean/src/gflags_reporting.cc
{hidden}/vcpkg/buildtrees/gflags/src/v2.2.2-d51934acae.clean/src/gflags_completions.cc
...
```

It adds the paths to all the source files locally, not just the ones installed by vcpkg. What should I do?

I tried building with cmake and adding -s, -g to cxxflags, but to no avail.

Comment: Hashing eash string will make it "complicated", but not impossible.

Comment: The `-g` option is probably counterproductive: you want *less* data in your binary, not more.  In fact, the strings you're seeing might be coming from debug information in the first place.

Comment: Have you tried stripping the executable?  On a unix system, you can do `strip prog` to remove symbol information.  That might remove the strings that you don't want people to see.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Hiding strings in your executable is not going to make it more secure (or whatever else you are trying to achieve). Whatever you are trying to hide can always be discovered through other means...

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes I already tried that, but to no avail.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't want to disclose the source file name in such an easy way, even if it can be discovered through other means. I need to distribute a project I'm working on to a client, and I don't want them to know what technology I used through the source file name.

Comment: Do you use the `assert` macro? Or use `__FILE__`?

Comment: @JinhaHwang "I don't want them to know what technology I used through the source file name" - Ok, if it's that simple, then why don't you just name your source files "xyzzy" and store them in a directory named "foobar".? - problem solved.

Comment: It sounds like a trust issue. Sell the program to the client.  If you don't trust the client, write a better agreement.

Comment: *"I don't want them to know what technology I used through the source file name"* - believe me there are a lot of (even better) ways to know the technology you have used to write a piece of software. Decompilers are a thing.

Comment: Like @MarcoBonelli mentioned - Your code _will_ be analyzed on assembler level if it's that hot. I'd give up and just make deals with those I trust enough.

Comment: If you have a sufficiently motivated adversary, then whatever you do while compiling you executable is going to be futile. Asm level inspection of your binary is going to reveal a lot more than just source file names. It'll probably reveal the compiler used, the target OS and platform, any "secret" algorithms you have in your code are going to be revealed clear as day. Just give up - you can't hide from a determined attacker who can inspect your code at the asm level (which is basically everyone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 main reasons for source filenames to appear in the executable:

- if you compile with debugging information, using `-g` for example.  Don't ship a debug build and strip debugging information from the executable by running `strip` with the appropriate flags, read the man page for your system.
- if you use the `__FILE__` macro, either directly in your program or macros or indirectly through `assert` macros or similar features. You can disable runtime checks performed by the `assert` calls by defining `NDEBUG` at compile time, for example for a `-DNDEBUG` compiler option. This should be the default for non debug builds, but check the compiler configuration.

Fixing the above problems should remove these strings from the executable file, but this is only the tip of the iceberg:

- other string literals will still be trivial to extract with the `strings` command or other tools,
- data files may contain sensitive information,
- system calls are trivial to track with `strace`,
- most C library call can be tracked and replaced using `llpreload`. Using static linking can make this more difficult, but may cause portability problems and is not supported for selected libraries on some targets, such as macOS.
- the code can always be reverse engineered with modern tools that are amazingly efficient, some of which even produce compilable C or C++ source code.

Needless to say, motivated hackers can investigate and not only find out what tools and/or technologies were used, but also what algorithms, what configuration parameters, data protection schemes, encryption methods and keys, licensing checks, etc.  Hackers are available for hire if your client does not have them in house.

You can hide some stuff from amateurs and make it a bit harder, but be aware that such protection is very limited, like anti-theft devices used in department stores.

You can also look for executable compressors and/or obfuscators that may be available for the target system: they could reduce the executable size and hide most strings at the same time, but uncompressing is not difficult for savvy developers, and running the program from a debugger lets the embedded loader do the decompression at startup time.  Again some of these tools are more advanced than others and raise the bar a little, but not sufficiently to protect yourself from dishonest clients.